# How to change the height of tableHeaderView in storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I was trying to customize the tableHeaderView in storyboard, the problem is that it seems that the tableHeaderView has fixed size. When I run this program, it looks like this: 
[my custom headerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJUwO.png)

Actually, the two gray UILabel is part of my headerView, but as you can see, it has fixed size. And I've already tried to change the size of my headerView in viewDidLoad:

```
    UIView *headerView = self.tableView.tableHeaderView;
    CGRect frame = headerView.frame;
    frame.size = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.width / 2.6);
    headerView.frame = frame;
    [self.tableView updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
```

P.S: I've seen some similar questions, but they just solved it with updateConstraintsIfNeeded, but I don't know it doesn't works for me. My Xcode version is 7.2, thanks!

Comment: add a constraint for height and assign it your dynamic value.

Comment: have you tried 
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;

Comment: @SaadChaudhry Well, I've tried use heightForHeaderInSection, the interesting thing is that, it just add another header under my custom headerView.

Comment: yes because it not a tableview's header but a section header, did you assigned your custom header to tableview?
  `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;`

Comment: @SaadChaudhry and I've tried to add a constraint, but it seems still not work for me. Maybe the view comes from the storyboard has been assigned a static frame, even if I can change the real frame of it, but from the tableView it just remains the original size.

Comment: can you share code in https://gist.github.com/

Comment: @SaadChaudhry Yes, I've tried to assign the headerView to tableView.tableHeaderView, but it still looks the same with the picture.

Comment: @SaadChaudhry I've created another project contains related files, and I tried to change some constraints, and know it seems worse. Here is my code :https://github.com/tcxy/HeaderViewTest

Comment: where is project file?

Comment: @SaadChaudhry Sorry for that, I'm not very skilled with git, I just create another repository and push my project file:https://github.com/tcxy/header

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
headerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the code:

```
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
UILabel *labelView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
labelView.text = @"Some Text";

[headerView addSubview:labelView];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
```

Comment: But in this way I just got a white space, I've already make my custom headerview in the storyboard, I just need to change its height.

Comment: The white space is UIView which you add in header. you need to add a label to give some text in header.

Comment: I see, in this way I just write some code about my custom headerView. In fact, I want to figure out how to finish all the process in storyboard with just a little extra code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with AutoLayout? Please follow this

```
- (void)sizeHeaderToFit
{
    UIView *header = self.tableView.tableHeaderView;

    [header setNeedsLayout];
    [header layoutIfNeeded];

    CGFloat height = [header systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
    CGRect frame = header.frame;

    frame.size.height = height;
    header.frame = frame;

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = header;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you create a custom `UIView` subclass and add labels in it?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 100;//whatever size you want
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let sectionInfo = fetchedResultsController!.sections! as [NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo]

    let headerView = CustomView()
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    headerView.addLabels()//add two labels in this method
    return headerView
}
```

Comment: Well, I just want to try to make custom headerView in the storyboard.

Comment: @WeiDu: Then create one and add labels with constraints in it, provide whatever height you want!